# How to send and receive from Pipes

Tags: c#, named-pipes

I have a c# winform app.

I also have a c# DLL.

The DLL is compiled in 32bit format.
The GUI is compiled using 64bit format.

I am using pipes to faciliatte messagubng between the 2 different compilations.

The DLL (client) sends to my GUI (Server) a byte array image.

This is my code for the server:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public delegate void NewMessageDelegate(System.Drawing.Bitmap NewMessage);
        private PipeServer pipeName;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        pipeName = new PipeServer();
        pipeName.PipeMessage += new DelegateMessage(PipesMessageHandler);
    }

    private void cmdListen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            pipeName.Listen("TestPipe");               
            txtMessage.Text = "Listening - OK";
            cmdListen.Enabled = false;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            txtMessage.Text = "Error Listening";
        }            
    } 

    private void PipesMessageHandler(System.Drawing.Bitmap message)
    {
        try
        {

            if (this.InvokeRequired)
            {
                pictureBox1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => pictureBox1.Image = message));
            }
            else
            {
                pictureBox1.Image = message;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }

    }
}
```

So, the User will press my 'cmdListen' button.

This is my client code (in the DLL):

```
class PipeClient
{
    public void Send(Bitmap frame, string PipeName, int TimeOut = 1000)
    {
        try
        {
            NamedPipeClientStream pipeStream = new NamedPipeClientStream(".", PipeName, PipeDirection.Out, PipeOptions.Asynchronous);
            pipeStream.Connect(TimeOut);
            Debug.WriteLine("[Client] Pipe connection established");
            byte[] _buffer = null;
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                frame.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                _buffer = ms.ToArray();
            }
            pipeStream.BeginWrite(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length, AsyncSend, pipeStream);
        }
        catch (TimeoutException oEX)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(oEX.Message);
        }
    }

    private void AsyncSend(IAsyncResult iar)
    {
        try
        {
            // Get the pipe
            NamedPipeClientStream pipeStream = (NamedPipeClientStream)iar.AsyncState;
            // End the write
            pipeStream.EndWrite(iar);
            pipeStream.Flush();
            pipeStream.Close();
            pipeStream.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception oEX)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(oEX.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

The 'Send' is called by a timer in my DLL to 'pump' images to my GUI app.

This all works.

What I need to add/do is to pass some parameters from server(GUI) to my DLL(client) BEFORE the timer is triggered.

So, in my client DLL I would have this function (eg)

```
public void InitDLL(object[] args)
{
    //do something with these parameters
    //start timer off
}
```

So, how can I call this function from my GUI using Pipes?

I have noticed that the PipeDirection can be set to be InOut.  But I am unsure how to simply add some code to my server app to send a message to my client.

Comment: Yes, if you want to use the same pipe for both directions, set the pipe to be bidirectional. You send data from the server the same way that the client sends data: get a stream, write to it. Note that some pipe-based implementations use two different pipes, one for each direction. That would work too.